# Tieing a LableFor to a CheckBoxFor inside a multiselect CheckBox List in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have built a mutli-select checkbox list

```
foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(i => item.SectionID)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(i => item.IsChecked)
    @Html.LabelFor(i => item.IsChecked, item.SectionTitle)
    <br />
}
```

While this generates a checkbox for each item and the proper text lable next to each box the problem comes that no matter which label you click it only toggles the first check box. How can I tie each label to the appropriate checkbox for this setup?

Answer (score 0):

```
  @Html.CheckBoxFor(i => item.IsChecked,new{id=item.SectionID})
```

Comment: I just tried that this morning and now clicking on the text does not check any boxes.